# How to convert a rtf string to plain text using R?

Tags: r, string, rtf, plaintext

I have lots of [rtf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) strings ([Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)) and I want to use R to obtain a plain text. Is it possible? There is one example bellow.

There are lots of ways using other languages, but it will be very useful if I found a "R way" to do the job.

```
rtfString <- "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"

plainText <- function(rtfString)

# The result will be something similar to this:

plainText

[1] "Sr. Presidente, Sras. e Srs. Parlamentares, ocupo esta tribuna para parabenizar a torcida paraense. O futebol paraense deu um show de civilidade neste final de semana, e a torcida bicolor do Papão da Curuzu, o Paysandu, está de parabéns, pois sagrou-se campeão do primeiro turno em cima do seu maior rival, vencendo o valoroso Clube do Remo.\nEstão de parabéns o Paysandu, o Governo do Estado, que deu um show de organização, a Justiça paraense, a polícia, os órgãos de segurança do Estado. Enfim, mais uma vez, parabéns à torcida bicolor.\nPaysandu, muitas e muitas glórias você ainda dará para essa sua brilhante torcida, que é a torcida bicolor de Belém do Pará.\nMuito obrigado, Sr. Presidente."
```

Comment: you could write it in C++ and then use the `Rcpp` package to deploy it from R.

Comment: Have you looked at the tm package and its PlainTextDocument function?  Also the qdap package as a plain text function.

Comment: @lawyeR, these functions do not do this job.

Comment: @lnNoam, it is a possible way, but I am really interest in use just R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of a few packages and some regex can accomplish this:

```
library(RCurl)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

decode_rtf <- function(txt) {

  txt %>%
    base64Decode %>%
    str_replace_all("\\\\'e3", "ã") %>%
    str_replace_all("\\\\'e1", "á") %>%
    str_replace_all("\\\\'e9", "é") %>%
    str_replace_all("\\\\'e7", "ç") %>%
    str_replace_all("\\\\'ed", "í") %>%
    str_replace_all("\\\\'f3", "ó") %>%
    str_replace_all("\\\\'ea", "ê") %>%
    str_replace_all("\\\\'e0", "à") %>%
    str_replace_all("(\\\\[[:alnum:]']+|[\\r\\n]|^\\{|\\}$)", "") %>%
    str_replace_all("\\{\\{[[:alnum:]; ]+\\}\\}", "") %>%
    str_trim

}

rtfString <- "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"

decode_rtf(rtfString)

## [1] "O SR. DUDIMAR PAXIUBA  (PSDB-PA. Sem revisão do orador.) - Sr. Presidente, Sras. e Srs. Parlamentares, ocupo esta tribuna para parabenizar a torcida paraense. O futebol paraense deu um  show  de civilidade neste final de semana, e a torcida bicolor do Papão da Curuzu, o Paysandu, está de parabéns, pois sagrou-se campeão do primeiro turno em cima do seu maior rival, vencendo o valoroso Clube do Remo.  Estão de parabéns o Paysandu, o Governo do Estado, que deu um  show  de organização, a Justiça paraense, a polícia, os órgãos de segurança do Estado. Enfim, mais uma vez, parabéns à torcida bicolor.  Paysandu, muitas e muitas glórias você ainda dará para essa sua brilhante torcida, que é a torcida bicolor de Belém do Pará.  Muito obrigado, Sr. Presidente."
```

I'm sure there are some edge cases this might bork on but it's definitely a start for you.

Comment: @hrbmstr, fantastic! I edited your answer to get the correct result. Of course it can be done in a more elegant way.

Comment: thx. `librtf` doesn't seem too difficult to get working on *nix, Windows & OS X so I'll try to post a Rcpp version in the next week or so.